# How to display gif animation in the bottom navigation bar in flutter？

Tags: dart, flutter

I use the gif image in the bottom navigation bar to replace the icon that comes with it, but clicking on the gif again after clicking it will not display the animation.

```
 class BottomNavigationBarHome extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        // TODO: implement createState
        return _BottomNavigationBarHomeState();
      }
    }

class _BottomNavigationBarHomeState extends State<BottomNavigationBarHome>{
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  var bottomTitle = ['home','menu','message','person'];
  var bottomIcons = ['res/icon/home.png','res/icon/menu.png','res/icon/message.png','res/icon/person.png'];
  var bottomIconsGif = ['res/icon/home.gif','res/icon/menu.gif','res/icon/message.gif','res/icon/person.gif'];

  var pageList = [
      new home(),
      new location(),
      new message(),
      new person()
  ];

  var title = '';
  var iconGif = ['res/icon/home.png','res/icon/menu.png','res/icon/message.png','res/icon/person.png'];


  void _onTapHandler(int index){
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
      iconGif =  ['res/icon/home.png','res/icon/menu.png','res/icon/message.png','res/icon/person.png'];
      iconGif[index] = bottomIconsGif[index];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: pageList[_currentIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Image.asset(iconGif[0],height: 30.0,),
              title: Text(bottomTitle[0],style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Image.asset(iconGif[1],height: 30.0,),
              title: Text(bottomTitle[1],style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Image.asset(iconGif[2],height: 30.0,gaplessPlayback: true,),
              title: Text(bottomTitle[2],style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Image.asset(iconGif[3],height: 30.0,),
              title: Text(bottomTitle[3],style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
          ),
        ],
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: _onTapHandler,
        ),
      ),

    );

  }

}
```

use flutter v1.0;I use the gif image in the bottom navigation bar to replace the icon that comes with it, but clicking on the gif again after clicking it will not display the animation.